# Inkscape command line: Need to convert SVG to eps without EPS+Latex: Omit text in EPS and create Latex File

Tags: svg, inkscape, eps

I need to convert an SVG to EPS and currently use inkscape to do this.

To convert the SVG using the Inkscape GUI version, I simply open the svg, and "Save As" '1.eps', unselecting the "EPS+Latex: Omit text in EPS and create Latex File" and "Rasterize filter effects" option.

How can I achieve this using inkscape command line. As I experienced that inkscape used EPS+Latex option as default even though user don't have mention --export-latext option in command line.

[image]